# Memory overflow with very large lists

Tags: python, list, memory

I got the following code:

```
import sys
from sentence_transformers import InputExample
from lib import DataLoader as DL

def load_train_data():
    train_sentences = DL.load_entire_corpus(data_corpus_path)  # Loading from 9GB files
    # 16GB of memory is now allocated by this process
    train_data = []
    for i in range(len(train_sentences)):
        s = train_sentences.pop()  # Use pop to release item for garbage collector
        train_data.append(InputExample(texts=[s, s]))  # Problem is around here I guess
    return train_data

train_data = load_train_data()
```

The files loaded in `DL.load_entire_corpus` contain lists of sentences.

The code crashes because more than 32GB of RAM are being allocated during the process. Until the for-loop around 16GB is being allocated. During the for loop it raises until 32GB which leads to a crash or a hanging system.
`print(sys.getsizeof(train_sentences) + sys.getsizeof(train_data))` within the for loop is never over 10GB. There is no other process that can allocate RAM.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`getsizeof()` generally goes only one level deep. For a list, it returns a measure of the bytes consumed by the list structure itself, but *not* bytes consumed by the objects the list contains. For example,

```
>>> import sys
>>> x = list(range(2000))
>>> sys.getsizeof(x)
16056
>>> for i in range(len(x)):
...     x[i] = None
>>> sys.getsizeof(x)
16056
```

See? The result doesn't change regardless of what the list *contains*. The only thing that matters to `getsizeof()` is `len(the_list)`.

So the "missing" RAM is almost certainly being consumed by the `InputExample(texts=[s, s])` objects you're appending to `train_data`.

Comment: How can I check the actual size of the list then? To go sure it's the `InputExample`

Comment: Not easily. You have to, in effect, write your own function that applies `getsizeof()` recursively. You can start here: https://code.activestate.com/recipes/577504/